# PHP Simple Login System - 500 Error

Tags: php, authentication, system

So, I'm in the process of making an SQL login system, and I figured I'd start out with something simple, like an IF to check the username and password, and then return you to the main index with a greeting in the top-right.
I did all this, and it should be working from what I see, but when I submit the login form  the server throws an `HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error)`.
I was hoping I could get some help here, as my IRC friend hasn't been able to find a solution. The login system encompasses 2 files, and their contents are:
*index.php:*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Kinz</title>
    <?php session_start(); ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <meta name="description" content="Kinz's personal website." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="kinz,php,login,fruity,css" />
    <meta name="author" content="Kinz" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainbar">
        <label class="menubar">Home</label>

        <?php if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == false || isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) == false) { ?>
        <form id="loginform" action="auth.php?login=true" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" class="login" id="login" name="loginSubmit" value="Login">
            <input type="password" class="login" id="password" name="password" value="Password">
            <input type="text" class="login" id="username" name="username" value="Username">
        </form> <?php } elseif ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) { ?>
            <label id="loginWelcome">Welcome, <?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>!</label> <?php } else { echo "Error."; } ?>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*auth.php:*

```
<?php session_start();
$user = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z1-9]/", '', $_POST['username']);
$pass = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z1-9]/", '', $_POST['password']);
$hpass = md5($pass);

if (isset($_POST['loginSubmit']) && $_GET['login'] == "true") {
    if ($user == "Admin" && $pass == "Password123") {
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
        header("Location: index.php"); exit();
    } else {
            print("<h1><b>Login failure.</b></h1>"); sleep(10);
            header("Location: index.php"); exit();
            }

    if (!$_SESSION['loggedin']) {
        header("Location: index.php"); exit();
    } else {
            header("Location: index.php"); exit();
    }
} ?>
```

I could not find any errors in my code, I'm hoping someone will. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I've noticed is that `session_start()` is not on the first line of your script.
`session_start()` must always be executed **before** sending any output!

Also, why this:

```
if (!$_SESSION['loggedin']) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
} else {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}/* THIS BIT */ else {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}/* TO HERE */
```

You can't have 2x "else" in 1 if-statement.

Comment: Thank you again, but, now it doesn't seem to be doing anything. It just takes a long time to load and then reloads the index page..

Comment: Could you please update the code in your post so we can review your changes?

Comment: Updated, and indented better.

Comment: `<?php session_start(); ?>` is still not at the beginning of your script (index.php). Also, `exit();` is not necessary when you're enclosing everything in if-statements.

Comment: Also you can remove `sleep(10);`. It's completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

After properly **indenting** your code, you will see that a `}` is missing.

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $user = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z1-9]/", '', $_POST['username']);
 $pass = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z1-9]/", '', $_POST['password']);
 $hpass = md5($pass);
 if (isset($_POST['loginSubmit']) && $_GET['login'] == "true") {
     if ($user == "Admin" && $pass == "Password123") {
         $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
         $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
         header("Location: index.php");
         exit();
     } else {
         print("<h1><b>Login failure.</b></h1>");
         sleep(10);
         header("Location: index.php");
         exit();
     }
     if (!$_SESSION['loggedin']) {
         header("Location: index.php");
         exit();
     } else {
         header("Location: index.php");
         exit();
     } // < Here's a missing } - Can't place two else-blocks after each other
} else {
     header("Location: index.php");
     exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: @Kinz Actually, the `}` should be moved a block up, because two `else` blocks cannot be placed after each other. Can you see the **importance of properly indenting code during development**?

Comment: Yes. I'll try to in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try and move `session_start()` in your index file at the top of the page. (It calls page headers.)

On side topic. What's the use of your `if-else`s? They all redirect to same page. Maybe this is just for testing, and you haven't defined `$_GET` variables for displaying messages or something like that?

Update. I somehow missed Artaexe's answer so this post is useless...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should write your code a little bit cleaner, it's easy'er to read. Is there an .htaccess file in your root directory? Or in any of the other directory's? It's a hidden file, if so, post the content of that file here.

Comment: I know my coding style is messy.. But a lone `}` on a line is unnerving to me, and there's no .htaccess file.